# Sorting through array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I try to display the test scores in the function sortArray, I can only access the memory address. How to I access the values of the scores?? Also is the sortArray function correct overall?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sortArray(int *[], int);

int main()
{
    int *testScores = nullptr;
    //dynamically allocate an array
    int scoreNUMS;
    int score;


    cout << "Please enter the total number of test scores" << endl;
    cin >> scoreNUMS;

    testScores = new int[scoreNUMS];
    //dynamically allocates an array large enough to hold scoreNUMS

    for(int i = 1; i <= scoreNUMS; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter student " << i << "'s test score" << endl;
        cin >> score;
        if (score <= -1)
        {
            cout << "Please enter positive numbers only!" << endl;
        }
        *(testScores + i) = score;
        //puts the input score in the array


    }

    sortArray(&testScores, scoreNUMS);

    return 0;
}
```

Im not sure if the function below is correct because I was unaware where to place the * and the &

```
void sortArray(int *array[], int size)
{
    bool swap;
    int temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for(int count = 0;count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            if(array[count] > array[count + 1])
            {
                temp = *array[count];
                array[count] = array[count + 1];
                array[count + 1] = &temp;
                swap = true;

            }
        }
    }while(swap);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << *(array + 1) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hint 1: function parameter `int *array[]` really is `int** array`. Hint 2: look into `std::vector` so you don't have to worry about this kind of stuff.

Comment: Your sort function is defintely wrong, but why are you passing a pointer to the array anyway? What is wrong with the normal way `void sortArray(int *array, int size)`?

Comment: I thought when using arrays you had to specify them with "[ ]"in the function prototype and header, is this incorrect?

Comment: @Cameron Yes, it is incorrect. The first part of my first comment refers to the fact that in a function parameter list, a parameter of type `T[]` really is `T*`. C++ inherits that weirdness from C. But `testscores` is just a pointer, it isn't an array. It points to the first element of an array returned by `new[]`, but it is still just a pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza thank you so much! I am making edits rn

Comment: With C / C++, even though testScores is a pointer, you can still use array syntax for a function parameter, prototype = void sortArray(int [], int), call = sortArray(testScores, scoreNUMS), function = void sortArray(int array[], int size) .

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** Array consist scoreNUMS elements, the first one is testScores[0] - first index is zero. And last index is scoreNUMS-1

You must write

```
for(int i = 0; i < scoreNUMS; i++)
```

**PS:** You can use next prototype:

```
void sortArray(int [], int);
```

*UPD:* passing an array to a function is performed by passing a pointer to the first element of the array. (Your array does not copied when you pass it to function)

And run function by this way: sortArray(testScores, scoreNUMS);

Comment: "arrays is C++ are always passed by reference." What is happening here is that a pointer is being passed, not a reference to an array. "Reference" has a different meaning in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza, sorry, your are rigth.